# Where can I find the list of all the interfaces commonly used by MyGeneration?

Tags: c#, .net, mygeneration

Where can I find the list of all the interfaces commonly used by MyGeneration?

(I am especially asking this to learn walking through all the tables in my DataBase with foreach loop)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have some common way of identifiying your entity classes (such as a common base class, or implemented interface). Then you can do a reflection query like:

```
from t in typeof(Entity).Assembly.ExportedTypes
where typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(t) || t.GetInterfaces.Any(i => i == typeof(CommonInterface))
select t
```

No compiler at hand, but this is the broad direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about the [MyGeneration Code Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/) you probaly need the interfaces to the databasemodell found [here in the My Generation svn Repository](http://mygeneration.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mygeneration/trunk/mymeta/Interfaces/)